# QSetting doesn't works fine for me

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, qsettings

I've wrote a simple application to use QSettings. Can someone tell me what wrong I'm doing here..

#### mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    QWidget *pMainWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *pMainLayout;
    QSettings *pSetting;

    QLabel *pLabel;
    QPushButton *pButtonShow;
    QPushButton *pButtonSet;
    QLineEdit *pLineEdit;

    QString pSettingFile;

public slots:
    void showSettingData();
    void setData();
};
```

#### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    pMainWidget = new QWidget (parent);
    pMainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pMainWidget);

    pLabel      = new QLabel("Output comes here",pMainWidget);
    pLineEdit   = new QLineEdit();
    pButtonShow = new QPushButton("Show", pMainWidget);
    pButtonSet  = new QPushButton("Set", pMainWidget);

    setCentralWidget(pMainWidget);
    pMainWidget->setLayout(pMainLayout);
    pMainLayout->addWidget(pLabel);
    pMainLayout->addWidget(pButtonShow);
    pMainLayout->addWidget(pLineEdit);
    pMainLayout->addWidget(pButtonSet);

    pSettingFile = QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"settings.ini";

    QObject::connect(pButtonShow, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showSettingData()));
    QObject::connect(pButtonSet, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setData()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::setData()
{
    QSettings Setting(pSettingFile, QSettings::NativeFormat);

    QString data = pLineEdit->text();
    Setting.setValue("baseurl", data);
}

void MainWindow::showSettingData()
{
    QSettings Setting(pSettingFile, QSettings::NativeFormat);

    if (Setting.contains("baseurl"))
    {
        QString data = Setting.value("baseurl").toString();
        pLabel->setText(data);
    }

}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I debug, it doesn't returns false for "Setting.contains("baseurl")"... Do we have to create the setting file?

Comment: Please please please restrict your question to one question. The principle on this site is one good question and one good answer. Also, can you provide a simple [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) example? Currently, you are referring to a setting issue, but you seem to have some UI code here, without a main function, project file, etc. You do not explain how you used the UI either.

Comment: As asked above, how do you use the UI? Can you please explain it? First, you are trying to use the set and then the show button? You mean, you are using the show button first, and you expect contains to return false, but it returns true without pressing the set button first?

Comment: yes.. I enter data in line edit, click the set button , then show button

Comment: I am lost ... If you set the data first, why should you get false for contains in show? It is expected to be true since you set it!

Comment: Have you tried QSettings::IniFormat instead of QSettings::NativeFormat? Native means registry on Windows, and that could cause issues. Which operating system are you using, android? And for that matter, which Qt version, Qt 4?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I am using on windows pc only.. It works now with NativeFormat... Still I dont know why it doesnt works in other way, Im using qt5. THanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not calling sync after setting the data. Try  to insert this line after the setting:

```
Setting.setValue("baseurl", data);
Setting.sync();
```

This should not be needed on Windows, but it seems to be necessary on Windows.

Also, as suggested in comments, I would suggest to use `QSettings::IniFormat` instead of `QSettings::NativeFormat` if you really want to use files rather than potentially registry on Windows.

You should also consider making the settings object as a class member rather than constructing it all the time.

Also, note that you may be using the wrong path unintentionally because you would have to add the "slash" character explicitly before the "settings.ini" file name. This is just a side note, however.

Comment: ok.. ill check this and mark as answer... And one thing, we shouldn't give a -1 if there is some point in an answer, correct?

Comment: @Abin: Why? You also confirmed yourself that does not solve the issue. While it is a useful comment, it is just a comment, so it should be either comment or a side note at the end of a real answer as an additional note IMHO. I would have probably even upvoted it as a comment as much as I did with your answer.

Comment: I've tried it. But didn't work, it is not creating the file. But QSettings::IniFormat will work and also this creates the file which will store data.